# MVC4 Why can't route as .html file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm use visual studio 2012 with MVC4.
I want some web page looks like .html suffix. So I add this code on `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Static",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}.html",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But the problem is I can't access it, the page always returns 404, and shows message:

> the resource is not found or removed.......

Is there any way can let it route as html page? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disable the handler for the `.html` extension.

Comment: Hi @Snake, thank you for reply. But the problem is I'm using visual studio 2012 debugging it now. So am I still need to go IIS config to disable it?  or can you tell me the way more specific for disable it? like change web.config, change to what?  thanks.

Comment: I'm add <system.webServer><staticContent><remove fileExtension=".html" /></staticContent></system.webServer> on Web.config,  but not working.

Comment: Are you using IIS Express? Or Casini?

Comment: Hi @Snake, I'm using IIS Express now when debug. when release, I'll use IIS. I need a solution for both.